# Understanding a for loop in a batch file to rename files by replacing strings

Tags: command-line, batch, cmd.exe

```
@echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Set "Pattern=rename"
Set "Replace=reuse"

For %%a in (*.jpg) Do (
Set "File=%%~a"
Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"
)
```

This renames .jpgs having substring 'rename'. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16128869/how-to-rename-file-by-replacing-substring-using-batch. Can anyone make me understand how the for loop does this job? Additionally, is it possible to use a `/f` switch here, to get rid of 'Access Denied'? And where can I place the `nul`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`For %%a in (*.jpg) Do (` - says get a directory listing of each file with extension `jpg` and give me the current name in the variable `%%a` and do something (which follows between the brackets).  I'm not sure where `Access Denied` would be coming from, presumably you lack file system rights to rename one or more files.

The real effort of this command is coming from [`enabledelayedexpansion`](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) which allows [variable replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) syntax.

`Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"` - The rename part can be simplified into `ren this that`... the trick is that second block with exclamation marks... which starts variable replacement.

`"!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"` - for variable `File` (set on line above to be full path, and filename of the current file in the `for` loop - which isn't necessary with this directory listing) replace all occurrences of `Pattern` with `Replace`.  `Pattern` is set on line 5 to *rename* while `Replace` is set on line 6 to *reuse* so this command says: in the given filename replace all occurrences of the string *rename* with *reuse*.

*To compile it all:*

1. For all files with extension `jpg` in the current directory
2. Rename the file so all occurrences of the string `rename` are now `reuse`

[`for /f`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) is for reading through the text content of one ore more files line by line - so no, it won't help you here.

Where's this `nul` coming from?

Comment: I want to redirect the output to `nul` (Say if the substring is not found). And will it work also for a Folder Renaming? What modification should a make (except `for /d...` to work with a folder name?

Comment: Use `> NUL 2>&1` after the command for which you want to redirect STDIN and STDERR to a null device.

Comment: Like this? `Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!" > NUL 2>&1` ? Not working.